# getting duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle

If I run the below query I am getting duplicate rows. Could anyone please help .

using distinct making query running long. never ending

```
adate -> 5-may-2022 rdate -> 28th -may-2022
```

query output getting as

```
7-may-2022
14-may-2022
21-may-2022
21-may-2022
21-may-2022
```

code is as below

```
select * from (
    with qry as (
        SELECT /* + parallel(12) */  adate     AS DATE1,
                     MIN(rdate)    AS DATE2,
           a.id
                FROM
                    t1                      a,
                    t2          b,
                    t3  c
                WHERE 
                        a.id = b.id
                GROUP BY
                    a.id,adate
    )select * from (
      select   id,
      date1 + level - 1 as CurDate,date1,date2
        from qry
      connect by level <= (date2 - date1) + 1)
      --group by id,date1 + level - 1,date1,date2 having count(date1 + level - 1)>1)
    where to_char(curdate,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN('SAT')
    and  (CurDate) NOT IN(date1,date2)) dual;
```

Comment: Please provide sample input data, table strcuture and expected outcome.

Comment: adate -> 5-may-2022 and rdate -> 28th -may-2022

query output getting as 
7-may-2022
14-may-2022
21-may-2022
21-may-2022
21-may-2022

expected output
7-may-2022
14-may-2022
21-may-2022

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Do these DATE values also contain time component? I mean, maybe all those 21st of May aren't just 21.05.2022 but e.g. 21.05.2022 07:23:13 and 21.05.2022 11:02:20 and so on. What is the result if you first `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'` and then run your query?

Comment: still getting duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Wrong use of generators... Read more:

- https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques
- https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/row-generators-part-2
- https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/follow-up-to-row-generators-part-2

Fix with minimal changes:

```sql
select * from (
    with qry as (
        SELECT /* + parallel(12) */  adate     AS DATE1,
                     MIN(rdate)    AS DATE2,
           a.id
                FROM
                    t1                      a,
                    t2          b,
                    t3  c
                WHERE 
                        a.id = b.id
                GROUP BY
                    a.id,adate
    )select * from (
      select   id,
      date1 + lvl - 1 as CurDate,date1,date2
        from qry
      ,lateral(select level lvl from dual connect by level <= (date2 - date1) + 1)
      --group by id,date1 + level - 1,date1,date2 having count(date1 + level - 1)>1)
    where to_char(curdate,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN('SAT')
    and  (CurDate) NOT IN(date1,date2)) dual;
```